# Translating raw SQL to Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Help me please with this query.

```
SELECT d.date, d.id, d.message, u.username 
FROM dialogs d JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.id 
AND d.is_deleted = 0 
WHERE d.id > ? ORDER BY d.id DESC LIMIT 30
```

There are messages with authors. Now I'm using DB::select for this query, but want something like:

```
Dialog::all(['date', 'id', 'message'])
            ->where('is_deleted', '=', 0)
            ->with('user')
            ->idDescending()
            ->take(30)
            ->get();
```

**Laravel 4.2**

Little adition. Works only if list of selected fields contains both local and foreign keys.

`Dialog::with('user')
                            ->where('is_deleted', '=', 0)
                            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                            ->take(30)
                            ->get(['date', 'id', 'message', 'user_id']);`

`public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User')->select(['username', 'id']);
    }`

If there no keys, user is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your relation setup correctly this should be good:

`$rows = Dialog::with('user')
    ->where('is_deleted', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(30)
    ->get(['date', 'id', 'message'])`

You should be able to access the user with

`foreach($rows as $row){
    $row->user->username;
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems that it works fine, but I need little changes because it returns collection object instead of array.
Can you help with some links? I didn't find in docs information about method calling order. Or only API is helpful?

Comment: Model::all() is shorthand for Model::get() and returns the collection, and you cant use query methods on it. I dont think the order matters for where orderBy etc tho. You can add `toArray()` after get to return the results as an array but the user will still be accessible thru `$rows[0]['user']['username`]` If you need the results to be in two dimensional array you need to use Fluent (QueryBuilder) and joins not Eloquent. [http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)